# How to check if words are there in a string using switch statements?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I have this code -

```
  const myFunc = () => {
    switch (transcript) {
      case transcript.split(" ").includes("hello"):
      case transcript.split(" ").includes("hey"):
      case "hi":
      case "hallo":
        const greetingArray = ["Hello!", "Hi!"];
        const randomItem =
          greetingArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * greetingArray.length)];
        setMyVar(randomItem);
        TTS(myVar, "english");

        break;
      case "bye":
        TTS("Goodbye", "english");
        break;
    }

    return myVar;
  };
```

As you can see, I tried to check if the words hey and hello is there in the transcript, but it isn't working.
How can I correct this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Note that the `.includes(...)` method returns a Boolean value of true|false, which is not suitable in your case.

Comment: @OlegBarabanov can you please suggest an alternative?

Comment: `if..else`, not `switch`.

Comment: @deceze actually, switch is essential. if...else is can't be used in my case.

Comment: And why is that?!

Answer (score 0):

`.includes` returns true/false so it would look like case true: case: false which is pointless code. It compiles (pseudo code) to something weird like this:

```js
val = "hello";
if (val: string == (val.split(" ").includes("hello"): boolean) || val == "hi" || etc) {
   ... do set var stuff
}
```

`case "word":` does work, however it would mean the transcript can ONLY and must be character by character identical to the "word".

So the includes do nothing, and because the following case's say "hallo" and "hi", hello/hey will not trigger any case and because theirs no default event it just escapes.

Your fix would be changing both your `transcript.split.includes` to simply "hello" and "hey".

Comment: Actually, I'm making a virtual assistant, so I can't expect exact words from the user.